# Symbolically implementing the following product

Tags: symbolic, products

I have two products I hope to compare symbolically and I am hoping to use `Mathematica` for this. They are as follows:
$$
\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} {(a_i + \cdots + a_{j-1}) + j - i \over j- i} \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
{\prod_{\ell = 1}^{n-1}\left(\prod_{j = \ell}^{n-1}\left[\sum_{i = 1}^j a_i + j - 1\right]\right) \over (n-1)!\cdot (n - 2)!\cdots 2!\cdot 1!} \tag{2}
$$
However, I'm not very familiar with the `Mathematica` syntax required to do this. Regards

Comment: Ponder on `Product[(Sum[a[k], {k, i, j - 1}] + j - i)/(j - i), {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, j - 1}]`, and you might be able to figure how to write what you need.

Comment: @0x4A4D I have come up with the code `(Product[(Sum[a[k], {k, 1, j}] + j - 1), {l, 1, n - 1}, {j, l, 
    n - 1}])/(Product[(n - i)!, {i, 1, n - 1}])` for the second product, but I am confused about how to implement the first product with the $1 \leq i < j \leq n$. I have the following so far: `Product[(Sum[a[k], {k, i, j - 1}] + j  - i)/(j  - i), {1 <= i < j <= 
   n}]`

Comment: Possibly using the `Boole` function?

Comment: Well, for the first: did you already ponder upon how I built the snippet in my first comment?

Comment: Ah! I just saw how your answer was actually a response to the first product. Many thanks. Does `Mathematica` have an `==` expression to test equivalence for two products such as these?

Comment: Not for something as general as this (you can verify for specific values of the upper limit, tho).

Comment: @0x4A4D I have been trying to evaluate this for some simple `a[k]` sequences and for `n = 5`, and I have been doing this using the `With[{n = 5}, Out[10]]` syntax, but it still gives me a symbolic expression in terms of `n` whereas I believe that I have specified all necessary variables?

Comment: Well, I can do this: `With[{n = 3}, {Product[(Sum[a[k], {k, i, j - 1}] + j - i)/(j - i), {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, j - 1}], Product[Sum[a[k], {k, 1, j}] + j - 1, {l, 1, n - 1}, {j, l, n - 1}]/Product[i!, {i, 1, n - 1}]}]`

Comment: Ah. Many thanks for your help! I really appreciate your consistent presence.

Comment: Suppose I name the product `Product[(Sum[a[k], {k, i, j - 1}] + j - i)/(j - i), {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, 
  j - 1}]` i.e., the first product, suppose I set that equal to `FultonHarris := prod`. Then why would the `With[{n = 3}, FultonHarris]` not yield the same result as your input? Is it because `FultonHarris` doesn't depend on `n`?

Comment: Something like that. Try `FultonHarris[n_Integer] := (* stuff *)`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first product can be written as:

```
Product[(Sum[a[k], {k, i, j - 1}] + j - i)/(j - i), {j, 1, n}, {i, 1, 
  j - 1}]
```

and your second one:

```
Product[Sum[a[k], {k, 1, j}] + j - 1, {l, 1, n - 1}, {j, l, n - 1}]/
 Product[i!, {i, 1, n - 1}]
```